# Best way to do system test in TFS?

Tags: testing, architecture, tfs

I have TFS 2010, and an application with a database that is populated
from some files.  Now the files might be as large as 200K lines, and I'd like
to produce a test that scans each record in the table and reports if they
follow our business logic.

What's the correct architecture to do this in TFS?

I tried making a unit test that opens an ODBC connection to the database
and tests each line, for instance:

```
 Assert.IsNotNull(trec("id").value, "Record ID is required")
```

but of course, it stops on the first failure, and I want to scan the 
whole table.

I could create my own structure from scratch, but my developers like the
reporting through TFS.  Could someone point me toward an example or reference?

Comment: Why would it stop at the first failure?

Comment: That's the model for a unit test -- on the first assertion that fails, it stops the test.

Comment: So this is ONE test. Of course it is not a unit test either way. Test stops because the assert actually throws an exception. Just use a boolean flag or failure counter while scanning. Then assert over the result.